# Python Pyinstaller MSYS problem with PyQtWebKit

Tags: python, pyinstaller, mingw-w64, qtwebkit, msys

**web_browser.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'web_browser.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.2
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(779, 257)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**web_browser_main.py**

```
from web_browser import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebView , QWebPage
import sys
class TestBrowserCode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.mainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.main_ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.main_ui.setupUi(self.mainWindow)
        self.mainWindow.showMaximized()
        
        self.open_google()
        
        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())
        
    def open_google(self):
        self.google_url = 'http://www.google.com'
        
        self.main_ui.chat_browser = QWebView()
        self.main_ui.chat_page = QWebPage()
        self.main_ui.chat_browser.setPage(self.main_ui.chat_page)
        self.main_ui.chat_browser.setUrl(QUrl(self.google_url))
        
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)


        self.main_ui.chat_browser.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 398))
        self.main_ui.chat_browser.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 398))
        
        
        self.main_ui.chat_browser.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.main_ui.chat_browser.setStyleSheet("background-color:white;border:1px solid #dadada;")
        
        self.main_ui.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.main_ui.chat_browser)
        
        self.main_ui.chat_browser.show()

program = TestBrowserCode()
```

1. Run the code from source:

```
Χρήστος@Chris-pc MINGW64 /c/python/scripts/Papinhio player/notes
$ python web_browser_main.py
```

(The site is displayed correct)

2. Make an .exe file ([full result here](https://files.fm/u/tj3cpf5y6))

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/Scripts/Papinhio player/notes/web_browser_main.py", line 4, in
 
    from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import QWebView , QWebPage
  File "", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "", line 657, in _load_unlocked
  File "", line 556, in module_from_spec
  File "", line 1101, in create_module
  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKit'
[17208] Failed to execute script web_browser_main
```

Result error import `PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets`

All that inside msys2 mingw64 console.
How can I compile the above files?

Answer (score 1):

```
pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import PyQt5.QtWebKit web_browser_main.py
```

The upper code includes the missing module QtWebKit.
I suggest to use --onedir instead of --OneFile because I think the output exe is more stable.
(I had a Segmentfault runtime error after some seconds in an application like the web_browser_main app)

Works now!!!

Comment: Please explain what the code does and how it does it.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 did it

Answer (score 0):

The upper code includes the missing module QtWebKit. I suggest to use --onedir instead of --OneFile because I think the output exe is more stable. (I had a Segmentfault runtime error after some seconds in an application like the web_browser_main app)

Works now!!!